# QGIS 2.4 match borders of two shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have two shapefiles of the same place, but one of them is wrong and I need to match the borders with the other one.

I am using QGIS 2.4 and could not do it so far.

Comment: Welcome to the site Santiago.  Could you please provide more details on your desired output?  How is one of the shapefiles wrong?  More details on how to ask GIS SE questions available here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Further to @Aaron's comment, including screenshots could also attract more potential answerers.

Comment: If I could post an image this will be easier to explain. When I say that one of the shapefiles is wrong, it means that the nodes of the borders of one of them must match the borders of the other, but they don´t. In ArcGIS I believe there´s a tool called "allign to shape" and I´m looking for one in QGIS so I don´t have to do it in ArcGIS. Thanks!